# Why CPU time is negative

Tags: c++, c, linux, timing

I am trying to measure the CPU time of following code - 
    struct timespec time1, time2, temp_time;

```
          clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);

          long diff = 0;

          for(int y=0; y<n; y++) {

                for(int x=0; x<n; x++) {

                float v = 0.0f;

                 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)

                     v += a[y * n + i] * b[i * n + x];

                       c[y * n + x] = v;

                   }

            }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);

        temp_time.tv_sec = time2.tv_sec - time1.tv_sec;

        temp_time.tv_nsec = time2.tv_nsec - time1.tv_nsec;

        diff = temp_time.tv_sec * 1000000000 + temp_time.tv_nsec; 

       printf("finished calculations using CPU in %ld ms \n", (double) diff/1000000);
```

But the time value is negative when i increase the value of n. 
Code prints correct value for n = 500 but it prints negative value for n = 700
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code structure -

```
void run(float A[], float B[], float C[], int nelements){
    struct timespec time1, time2, temp_time;

          clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);

          long diff = 0;

          for(int y=0; y<nelements; y++) {

                for(int x=0; x<nelements; x++) {

                float v = 0.0f;

                 for(int i=0; i<nelements; i++)

                     v += A[y * nelements + i] * B[i * nelements + x];

                       C[y * nelements + x] = v;

                   }

            }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);

        temp_time.tv_sec = time2.tv_sec - time1.tv_sec;

        temp_time.tv_nsec = time2.tv_nsec - time1.tv_nsec;

        diff = temp_time.tv_sec * 1000000000 + temp_time.tv_nsec; 

       printf("finished calculations using CPU in %ld ms \n"(double) diff/1000000); 
}
```

This function abovr is called from different fil as follows:

```
SIZE = 500;

a = (float*)malloc(SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(float));

b = (float*)malloc(SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(float));

c = (float*)malloc(SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(float));

//initialize a &b
run(&a[SIZE],&b[SIZE],&c[SIZE],SIZE);
```

Comment: Are you sure your `a` and `b` arrays are big enough? you could be overflowing them and scribbling on random bits of memory, including your time1 value.

Comment: Have you properly allocated memory for `a[], b[] and c[]`? Sometimes out of bound writings cause strange problems. Might want to use `std::vector<>` for such `arrays`.

Comment: You're values are wrapping: If t2.tv_sec = t1.tv_sec + 1, but t2.tv_nsec < t1.tv_nsec, then tmp.tv_nsec could be much larger value than 10^9, which may be interpreted as a negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like an overflow use `unsigned long` or better `double` for `diff`

Answer (score 0):

The 'tv_nsec' field should never exceed 10^9 (1000000000), for obvious reasons:

```
if (time1.tv_nsec < time2.tv_nsec)
{
    int adj = (time2.tv_nsec - time1.tv_nsec) / (1000000000) + 1;

    time2.tv_nsec -= (1000000000) * adj;
    time2.tv_sec += adj;
}

if (time1.tv_nsec - time2.tv_nsec > (1000000000))
{
    int adj = (time1.tv_nsec - time2.tv_nsec) / (1000000000);

    time2.tv_nsec += (1000000000) * adj;
    time2.tv_sec -= adj;
}

temp_time.tv_sec = time1.tv_sec - time2.tv_sec;
temp_time.tv_nsec = time1.tv_nsec - time2.tv_nsec;

diff = temp_time.tv_sec * (1000000000) + temp_time.tv_nsec;
```

This code could be simplified, as it makes no assumptions about the sign of the 'tv_sec' field. Most Linux sys headers (and glibc?) provide macros to handle this sort of timespec arithmetic correctly don't they?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible problem causes is that the `printf` format is for a long signed integer value (`%ld`), but the parameter has the double type. To fix the problem is necessary change `%ld` to `%lf` in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your print statement:

```
printf("finished calculations using CPU in %ld ms \n", (double) diff/1000000);
```

The second parameter you pass is a double, but you are printing out this floating point value as a long (%ld).  I suspect that's half your problem.

This may generate better results:

```
printf("finished calculations using CPU in %f ms \n", diff/1000000.0);
```

I also agree with keety, you likely should be using unsigned types Or you could possibly avoid the overflow issues altogether by staying in millisecond units instead of nanoseconds.  Here's why I stick with 64-bit unsigned integers and just stay in the millisecond realm.

```
unsigned long long diffMilliseconds;

diffMilliseconds = (time2.tv_sec * 1000LL + time2.tv_nsec/1000000) - (time1.tv_sec * 1000LL + time1.tv_nsec/1000000);

printf("finished calculations using CPU in %llu ms \n", diffMilliseconds);
```